# Probability distribution for weights in Gym machine?

Tags: probability, distributions, modeling, discrete-data, compound-distributions

Below is the image of weights in Gym, I would like to know what probability distribution that would fit the wear and tear of the weights.

Below are my initial thoughts:

(1) Has to be discrete distribution
(2) Its a choice problem
(3) Data is skewed
(4) Outlier spike at weight = 100

Some probability distribution to consider:

1. Beta Binomial distribution
2. Negative binomial distribution (but can't have indefinite weights, has to be truncated at 130)

Questions:

1. What is the right probability distribution to model this problem?
2. How do you handle spike at 100?

[image]

Comment: How do you measure "wear and tear"?  What is it you're really trying to model?  One would think it might be *frequency of use,* but that likely has a nonlinear relationship with visible wear and you would first need to study that relationship empirically.

Comment: @whuber wear and tear, the white part of these weights will be measured. Frequency of use of each weight is what I would like to model.

Comment: In addition to the need for studying the relationship between frequency of use and wear, you need to consider the possibility that (say) stronger people are more accurate with placing the pins.  In other words, you need to think about whether the visible amount of wear is even directly related to frequency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny question, I have seen this picture multiple times on the internet.

First of all, I would say that in general there is not a "right" probability distribution to fit empirical data. Models are always simplifications of reality. However, some models are definitely better than others.

In this case, I would say that Beta-binomial are negative binomial are both suitable candidates. You could even try Poisson (as the data looks somewhat normal expect for discrete nature and the spike at 100) with also truncation at 130. Note that the negative binomial is a generalisation of Poisson and you could compare fits. I think all of these are reasonable options. The advantage of Beta-binomial is that it handles the upper bound of the data well so you do not need truncation so I would first start with that one. Also note that for large n, Beta-binomial is well approximated by negative binomial so it should also not matter much (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution).

For your second question, I would recommend using a mixture distribution (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution). I think this is necessary to handle the discrete spike (as there are not really standard distributions out there with such behaviour). You could do this by first estimating the mass at 100 kg (let's say $w = 2\%$) and then using a mixture distribution in the following way. Let $\delta_{100}(x)$ denote the Dirac delta distribution that only assigns probability mass to the discrete point at $x = 100$ and 0 otherwise. Let $P$ denote a Beta-binomial (or any of the other above discussed) distribution. Then your mixture distribution $P_M$ becomes something like
$$
P_M(x) = w \delta_{100} + (1 - w) P.
$$
You can easily simulate from this distribution by drawing some $B \sim Ber(w)$ and set $X = 100$ if $B = 1$ and draw  $X \sim P$ otherwise.

One easy way to estimate the above parameters is to set $w$ equal to the mass at 100. Then you should fit your Beta-binomial to the data where you remove all/most of the mass of 100 (this is important otherwise you push your beta-binomial parameters a bit so that the distribution shifts upwards). For beta-binomial parameters, you could use method of moments (see Wikipedia for the expressions). Although this estimation procedure is not completely rigorous, I think it would give you a decent approximation.

You can always still compare different fitted distributions with the underlying empirical distribution function using Kolmogorov-Smirnov tests to get a quantitative measure of which distribution fits best.

Comment: Thank you. When $\delta_ {100}$ does it mean that in the equation you need  actual value in this case 100. 

Since the spike happens only in 100, not sure if I need dirac delta for all >= 100?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, let me edit that. I wrote that it equals 1 for $x\geq 100$ as I was referring to the cdf. For more information, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function.